# VMware ESXi 4.1 snapshot of server 2008R2 machine generates 2 indentical snapshots

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-esxi, snapshot

I have 2 VMs that are failing to get veeam backups, and it appears that the culprit is vmware snapshots. We are running Vsphere ESXi 4.1 build 320092, we have multiple server 2008R2 machines that take snapshots fine, but when with these two VMs when I take a snapshot I get 2 identical snapshots a few seconds apart. The snapshot manager only shows 1 snapshot, but there are 2 files 1 number off, that are identical sizes. There is only one disk on each VM, so that isn't the problem. Has anyone seen this behavior before and know how to fix it?

Here are the files after a bad snapshot

```
VM-XXX-000001-ctk.vmdk
VM-XXX-000001-delta.vmdk
VM-XXX-000001.vmdk
VM-XXX-000002-ctk.vmdk
VM-XXX-000002-delta.vmdk
VM-XXX-000002.vmdk
VM-XXX-2a659dbf.hlog
VM-XXX-2a659dbf.vswp
VM-XXX-Snapshot286.vmsn
VM-XXX-aux.xml
VM-XXX-ctk.vmdk
VM-XXX-flat.vmdk
VM-XXX-vss_manifests286.zip
VM-XXX.nvram
VM-XXX.vmdk
VM-XXX.vmsd
VM-XXX.vmx
VM-XXX.vmxf
vmware-20.log
vmware-21.log
vmware-22.log
vmware-23.log
vmware-24.log
vmware-25.log
vmware.log
```

VM-XXX-000001.vmdk and VM-XXX-000002.vmdk are the exact same size.

Comment: Can you list the files that you see in the Datastore Browser after you've taken a snapshot of one of the affected VM's.

Comment: I talked with VMware and they think it might have something to do with a recent migration, I was told the techs I talked to had never seen this problem before. Removing the vm from inventory and adding it back fixed the problem, but I'll update after we dig into it a bit.

Comment: Very interesting bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with VMware this is actually normal behavior having to do with how VMware works with Microsoft VSS in 2008 machines. See the last paragraph on page 25 of http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vddk/vadp_vsphere_backup12.pdf